# nginx: Redirecting without changing the address line in the browser

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have a support system installed with a different hoster and want the address from my web application to contain a link to that support system. However, the domain name I registered together with this support system is completely unrelated to the name of my web application and might confuse people.

Is it possible to enter a link like www.example.com/support and then have nginx redirect to the designated domain without changing the address line itself?

I tried rewrite, but it completely redirects you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [proxying](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule) it, but this is just a tip, I haven't tried it yet.

```
location / {
  proxy_pass        http://desired_domain;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;

  # original host uses built-in $host variable, replace it with desired name
  # proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header  Host       desired_hostname;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use frames. frameset hosted on your machine with one frame inside pulling contents From URL you want to hide.